# SSRS - Two different reports in one Excel?

Tags: reporting-services

I am pretty new to SSRS, so forgive me if I am asking something that is either obviously not possible (or easy) - I haven't found what I am looking for so far!!

I have a Detailed report, which splits by group onto multiple Excel tabs (pages).  I also have a separate Summary report which outputs onto one page.

I want to merge these two into one report, so the users receive just one email, with tab 1 showing the Summary report and tab 2 on wards showing all the Detail.

The datasets come from two stored procedures and whilst related, they are different so I can't use the same dataset.

Is this possible in SSRS?

Thanks

Mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take your Detailed report and insert a subreport at the start of it. Set the subreport properties to point your Summary report.

If you have any manually set parameters in the Summary report, you'll need to set them up in the Detailed report (if they don't already exist) so you can pass the parameters to the subreport.

Now you have a single report with everything in.

Comment: HI Alan, thanks for the pointer of using Subreport.  After having a few difficulties, I decided to create a new report and have both the summary and detail as sub-reports.  I've got this working 99%, however I am getting a blank tab at the end of my Detail report, which is not there when I run the report standalone? Not sure if its something to do with the positioning on the canvas?  I have checked and it has no "Page break" after setting.  Any thoughts?

Comment: I'm not sure. I would usually check (like it appears you have done) that there are no page breaks set after groups etc. If you have anything in any containers (rectangles usually) then check they do not have breaks set. Other than that I would make sure that the subreports are narrow enough to fit within the main report `minus` margins and that there is no white space around the subreports where possible as this can end up outside the page limits creating a new blank page. Good luck!